# Unable to read the page with requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to read the page `https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/index/lci.html?lang=zh`. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/index/lci.html?lang=zh'
res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
res.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
```

However, `res.text` contains no data of the page.

I also tried:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
```

It says: `pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol error Target.closeTarget: Target closed.`

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: The first one works for me. When you print res.text or soup.prettify() is it blank or is it throwing errors?

Comment: Yes. what should be the correct way to get the data?

Comment: If I execute the first 5 lines (except for the import of BeautifulSoup), res.text contains what appears to HTML. What makes you think it "contains no data of the page" when you do it?

Comment: You might try: text = res.content.decode('utf-8-sig')

Comment: I tried `res.content.decode('utf-8-sig')` but it does not contain the data.

Comment: A simple way to check is to test if `ltn20190617066_c.pdf` is in `res.text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www1.hkexnews.hk/ncms/json/eds/lcisehk1relsdc_1.json

You are welcome.

In case you are curious, the "Network" tab of the DevTools is your friend.

Comment: Thank you very much, Imperishable Night. Your solution is great. But if there is no json file appears, what is the correct way to get the data I want?

Comment: Many dynamic pages like this will be getting their data from a separate url. It is usually a json file, although it may not have the `.json` extension. In any case, if you open the DevTools and refresh the page, you can see all urls requested by the browser in the "Network" tab. With a little experience you can usually quickly spot the file you are looking for.

Comment: How about `https://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/mutualmarket_c.aspx?t=sh&t=sh`? I cannot get the .json link.

Comment: Well, that is an aspx, so all the data you see are actually in the first HTTP response. So revert to your original method and `BeautifulSoup` it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Try another page to load. I ran the script and it works.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # You missed a character 'l'

url = "https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/index/lci.html?lang=zh"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    els = soup.select("#Callable\ Bull\/Bear\ Contracts")
    print(els[0])
```

I got:

```
 <input checked="" class="filterCheckBox strcProdCheckBox" data-value="Callable Bull/Bear Contracts" id="Callable Bull/Bear Contracts" name="Property" tabindex="-1" type="checkbox"/>
```

Try to:

```
curl --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geckoe/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36" https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/index/lci.html?lang=zh
```

Comment: I tried your code but still cannot get the data we want.

Comment: Please refer to the figure in my question. I want to get the data in the red box.

Comment: data you want are placed on: https://www1.hkexnews.hk/ncms/json/eds/lcisehk1relsdc_1.json?_=1560746618671